# How to move a file without waiting to complete in Batch (this should be working)

Tags: file, batch-file

**Details:** 
Using a program called MCEBuddy to process video files and when completed MCEBuddy will run a users batch file for custom processing. In this batch file, I fix up a few things and simply move the proccessed video to it's final location.

**Goal:**
To allow the batch file to return to MCEBuddy and not wait until the move has completed. Currently MCEBuddy will not resume before the entire file (video) has been moved, I don't want that.

I have 2 batch files, the first simply passes the parameters to the second batch file.

I have search and search, and even asked the developer over at MCEBuddy and is seems that everything I have tried just doesn't work.

The first Batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET BatFile="E:\VideoCaptures\Cleaned Files\TVTransfer.bat"
SET OutputFileName="%~n1"
SET InputFileName="%~n2"
SET FolderOutput="%~3"
SET WideoWidth="%~4"
SET OutputExtension="%~5"
SET OutputFileSize="%~z1"
SET OADMonth="%~7"
SET OADDay="%~8"
SET OADYear="%~9"

START "MCE Move" /b cmd /c Call %BatFile% %OutputFileName% %InputFileName% %FolderOutput% %WideoWidth% %OutputExtension% %OutputFileSize% %OADMonth% %OADDay% %OADYear%
```

The second Batch file (the part that moves the file)

```
START "MCE Move" /b cmd /c move /y "%OUTPUT_FOLDER%\%~1%OUTPUT_Ext%" %sPAT%\%MMDDYYYY%
```

I have also tried:

```
START "MCE Move" /MIN cmd /c move /Y "%OUTPUT_FOLDER%\%~1%OUTPUT_Ext%" %sPAT%\%MMDDYYYY%
```

and:

```
START "MCE Move" /MIN /b cmd /c move /Y "%OUTPUT_FOLDER%\%~1%OUTPUT_Ext%" %sPAT%\%MMDDYYYY%
```

and many other iterations, but none will allow MCEBuddy to resume before the file has completed it's move.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone right now. But have you tried

```
START "" "MCE Move" /b cmd /c move /y "%OUTPUT_FOLDER%\%~1%OUTPUT_Ext%" %sPAT%\%MMDDYYYY%
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no that does not work, and will not even move the file.

Comment: Now that I'm not on my phone, I looked at your batch file a little closer, while I don't know jack about what MCE Move is, in your first batch file, last line, you're starting MCE Move, than calling the second batch file which is also starting MCE Move. Is that the way it's suppose to be? Maybe instead of calling the batch file, you could `start` the batch file?

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. My understand is that the "MCE Move" parameter is just the window title. 

I've tried simply using CALL, and while it works, it does not reach my goal.

I've tried using CMD /C but it fails to work at all. 

I've tried using a different name "MCE Post Bat", but does not reach my goal.